# Minimal sum of distances in Manhattan metric in c

Tags: c, algorithm

I would need help with my code. I have R*S grid and N points. On every point are some people. I need to find point in grid with minimal sum of steps for people from all entered points. Distances are counted in Manhattan metric. Lines are numbered from 0 to R-1 and, column are numbered from 0 to S-1. On first line I have R, S and N and on N following lines are coordinates of N points and number of people located on this points. If exist more points with same sum of steps then just write one. This algorithm find median, but it probably not right answer. Please can you advice me some algorithm, that give me correct answer?
Example of input:

```
5 5 3
1 1 4
4 3 3
2 4 1
```

Example of output:

```
2 2
```

I write this code, but it doesn´t work. Can you help me with fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int *)a > *(int *)b) - (*(int *)a < *(int *)b);
}

int main(void) {
    int N, n, i, count, rx, ry, R, S;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &R, &S, &N);
    int a[N][2];
    int b[N][2];
    long int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &a[i][0], &b[i][0], &a[i][1]);
        b[i][1] = a[i][1];
        sum = sum + a[i][1];
    }

    n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    qsort(a, n, sizeof *a, cmp);
    if (sum % 2 == 1) {
        count = (sum + 1) / 2;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            count = count - a[i][1];
            if (count == 0) {
                rx = a[i][0];
                break;
            }
            if (count < 0) {
                rx = a[i-1][0];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sum % 2 == 0) {
        count = sum / 2;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            count = count - a[i][1];
            if (count == 0) {
                rx = (int)round((a[i][0] + a[i][0]) / 2);
                break;
            }
            if (count < 0) {
                rx = a[i][0];
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    if (sum % 2 == 1) {
        count = (sum + 1) / 2;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            count = count - b[i][1];
            if (count == 0) {
                ry = b[i][0];
                break;
            }
            if (count < 0) {
                ry = b[i - 1][0];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sum % 2 == 0) {
        count = sum / 2;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            count = count - b[i][1];
            if (count == 0) {
                ry = (int)round((b[i][0] + b[i][0]) / 2);
                break;
            }
            if (count < 0) {
                ry = b[i][0];
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    printf("%d %d", rx, ry);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to say more than “it doesn’t work.” You must state what the problem is. It crashes? It hangs and never prints anything? It prints incorrect output? For what input? What is the expected outpit, and what does it print instead?

Comment: Please don't ask such question on this forum. If you have any error please mention what error you are getting and just put the code you have problem with

Comment: Do you need such complicated stuff? Since Manhattan distance is just the sum of differences of individual coordinates, to me it feels like you just need the weighted average of x and y coordinates, separately

Comment: Thanks for fast reaction. It print incorrect output. Expected output are coordinates of optimal point for meeting (points with minimal sum of steps) and it must be integer. So should I use weighted average of x and y coordinates and round it?

Comment: Note `(sum%2 == 1)` is not true if `sum < 0`.  Recommend `(sum%2)` or `(sum%2 != 0)`.

Comment: `rx = (int)round((a[i][0]+a[i][0])/2);` likely does not do what you think.  `(a[i][0]+a[i][0])/2` is _integer_ division.  The call to `round()` serves no purpose here.

Comment: Thanks for reaction. In this case, sum is positive integer, because input are positives integers. And thanks for advice about round(). I remove it. And the algorithm itself is correct?

Comment: 1) "it doesn´t work" --> What was you result.  2) `R` is not used here.  What is the role of `R,S`?

Comment: Sorting is likely wrong.  (`cmp()` acts as if `a` was 1D array.) Verify the result of the sort is as desired.  Explain how you want a 2D array to be sorted.

Comment: I want to sort this array by first dimension and I think it work correct. I don´t use R,S here (R is max x value and S is max y value) because I computing median. When I think about it, algorithm may be wrong. I try to describe what I want. I have N points and every point has value for step. For example when I move one step from point (1,1) with value 4, distance which I count is 4. I need to find optimal point, where sum of distances is minimal. I try to do it for x and y separately because I  solve it in Manhattan metric.

Comment: Do not add crucial details in comments, they may be deleted at any time. There is an [edit] button right under your question in case you want to change or add something to it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your approach, there are multiple problems:

- you should check the return values of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.
- you should check the dimensions to avoid potential undefined behavior
- your distance computations seem incorrect
- your tests on the parity of `sum` do not seem to be relevant.

I would first try a brute force approach:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int N, R, S, i, row, col, best_row, best_col;
    struct { int row, col, count; } *points;
    long int sum, best_sum;

    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &R, &S, &N) != 3 || R < 0 || S < 0 || N < 0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    points = calloc(N, sizeof *points);
    if (points == NULL) {
        printf("allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d %d %d", &points[i].row, &points[i].col, &points[i].count) != 3) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    best_row = best_col = -1;
    best_sum = LONG_MAX;

    for (row = 0; row < R; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < S; col++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                sum += points[i].count * (abs(row - points[i].row) + abs(col - points[i].col));
            }
            if (best_sum > sum) {
                best_sum = sum;
                best_row = row;
                best_col = col;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", best_row, best_col);
    free(points);
    return 0;
}
```

Output for your test input:

```
1 1
```

The time complexity is horrible, but it does not matter for small sample sets. You can reduce the complexity by computing the sums of horizontal distances and vertical distances separately.